# DynamoDB collection type conflict resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been unable to find any documentation on how, if at all, DynamoDB handles conflicts in its `set`, `list`, and `map` collection types. My current understanding is that DynamoDB uses a last-writer-wins strategy. That is to say, if two concurrent writers both add to a set, one of those additions could be lost.

This is different from two other databases I have used, Cassandra and Riak. Both have well-defined conflict resolution strategies, as they back these types with CRDTs. So, modulo other failure modes, concurrent additions to a set will always eventually result in both additions taking place.

Because that Amazon's documentation doesn't cover it, I'm inclined to believe that there is no conflict management of any kind. But, I'd love to know if anyone has an other information and/or first-hand experience.

Comment: did you check dynamodb transaction? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html

Comment: What I’m really interested in is the collection types behavior outside of transactions. CRDTs don’t really make sense to use if you wrap everything in a transaction, because conflict won’t happen.